# Number input box in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a number input box which will accept numbers only.

My initial value approach was to replace value and set it again to itself.

#### Subscribe approach

```js
function vm(){
  var self = this;
  self.num = ko.observable();
  self.num.subscribe(function(newValue){
    var numReg = /^[0-9]$/;
    var nonNumChar = /[^0-9]/g;
    if(!numReg.test(newValue)){
      self.num(newValue.toString().replace(nonNumChar, ''));
    }
  })
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: num" />
```

Now this approach works but will add another cycle of subscribe event, so I tried to use a custom binding so that I can return updated value only. New to it, I tried something but not sure how to do it. Following is my attempt but its not working. Its not even updating the observable.

#### Custom Binding attempt

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.numeric_value = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    console.log(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor())
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, function() {
      var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
      return value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
    });
  },
};

function vm() {
  this.num = ko.observable(0);
  this.num.subscribe(function(n) {
    console.log(n);
  })
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="number_value: num, valueUpdate:'keyup'">
  <span data-bind="text: num"></span>
</div>
```

So my question is, Can we do this using custom bindings and is it better approach than subscribe one?

---

#### Edit 1:

As per [@user3297291](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297291/user3297291)'s answer, `ko.extenders` looks more like a generic way for my subscribe approach. I'm looking for an approach (if possible in Knockout), which would clean value before it is set to observable.

---

I have taken reference from following articles:

- [How to update/filter the underlying observable value using a custom binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656792/how-to-update-filter-the-underlying-observable-value-using-a-custom-binding)
- [How can i update a observable in custom bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128433/how-can-i-update-a-observable-in-custom-bindings)

Note: In the first example, they are using jQuery to set the value. I would like to avoid it and do it using knockout only

Comment: I think custom bindings will be a better alternative to subscribes because it is reusable so you can use it in other places of your application that require the same functionality.
Have a look at this jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tdkhypnL/1/ not sure if this is what you are after.

Comment: @klikas agree to your point. I'm planning to implement something similar to `textInput` but little tied up stuff. Will add answer later. Also, in your fiddle, characters are visible for fraction of second and for some cases(if 1 character is entered), character is retained.

Comment: you are correct, my solution isnt perfect but will try to fix it when i fond some time as it was a bit rushed just to illustrate the concept :)

Comment: @klikas I have added an answer. Not sure if its the best option but I guess should be improved and used. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I´m on favor of use extender as [user3297291](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297291/user3297291)'s aswer.

Extenders are a flexible way to format or validate observables, and more reusable.

Here is my implementation for numeric extender

```js
//Extender

ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, options) {
  //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
  var result = ko.pureComputed({
    read: target, //always return the original observables value
    write: function(newValue) {
      var newValueAsNum = options.decimals ? parseFloat(newValue) : parseInt(newValue);
      var valueToWrite = isNaN(newValueAsNum) ? options.defaultValue : newValueAsNum;
      target(valueToWrite);
    }
  }).extend({
    notify: 'always'
  });

  //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
  result(target());

  //return the new computed observable
  return result;
};

//View Model

var vm = {
  Product: ko.observable(),
  Price: ko.observable().extend({
    numeric: {
      decimals: 2,
      defaultValue: undefined
    }
  }),
  Quantity: ko.observable().extend({
    numeric: {
      decimals: 0,
      defaultValue: 0
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

**Edit**

I get your point, what about and regular expression custom binding to make it more reusable?

Something like this.

```js
function regExReplace(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

  var observable = valueAccessor();
  var textToReplace = allBindingsAccessor().textToReplace || '';
  var pattern = allBindingsAccessor().pattern || '';
  var flags = allBindingsAccessor().flags;
  var text = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
  if (!text) return;
  var textReplaced = text.replace(new RegExp(pattern, flags), textToReplace);

  observable(textReplaced);
}

ko.bindingHandlers.regExReplace = {
  init: regExReplace,
  update: regExReplace
}


ko.applyBindings({
  name: ko.observable(),
  num: ko.observable()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<input type="text" data-bind="textInput : name, regExReplace:name, pattern:'(^[^a-zA-Z]*)|(\\W)',flags:'g'" placeholder="Enter a valid name" />
<span data-bind="text : name"></span>
<br/>
<input class=" form-control " type="text " data-bind="textInput : num, regExReplace:num, pattern: '[^0-9]',flags: 'g' " placeholder="Enter a number " />
<span data-bind="text : num"></span>
```

Comment: The point is, first variable will update, then it will fire notify event and your extender will listen to it, Then again you will parse and set new value and again a cycle will happen. I want to eliminate this extra cycle.

Comment: I get your point, please check my response update, hope it helps

Comment: this is very close to what I was expecting. I'll try to implement it

Answer (score 4):

I think you can divide the problem in to two parts:

1. Making sure the user can only input numbers, or
2. Making sure your viewmodel value is a number rather than a string.

If you only need part 1, I'd advice you to use default HTML(5) features:

```
<input type="number" step="1" />
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

If you want to make sure the user cannot enter any other than a number, and want to use the value in your viewmodel as well, I'd use an extender. By extending the observable, you can change its value before any subscriptions are fired.

The knockout docs provide an excelent example on their [documentation page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html):

Note that when you use the extender, you don't need to worry about the `pattern` or `type` attribute anymore; knockout modifies the value instantly as soon as it's set.

```js
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
  //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
  var result = ko.pureComputed({
    read: target, //always return the original observables value
    write: function(newValue) {
      var current = target(),
        roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
        newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : +newValue,
        valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

      //only write if it changed
      if (valueToWrite !== current) {
        target(valueToWrite);
      } else {
        //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
        if (newValue !== current) {
          target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
        }
      }
    }
  }).extend({
    notify: 'always'
  });

  //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
  result(target());

  //return the new computed observable
  return result;
};

var vm = {
  changes: ko.observable(0),
  myNumber: ko.observable(0).extend({
    numeric: 1
  })
};

vm.myNumber.subscribe(function() {
  vm.changes(vm.changes() + 1);
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: myNumber">

<div>2 times <span data-bind="text: myNumber"></span> is <span data-bind="text: myNumber() * 2"></span>.</div>
<div> Changes: <span data-bind="text: changes"></span></div>
```

Comment: Will `target(valueToWrite);` trigger extender again? Also does pureComputed not expects pure function. Not sure what are its repercussion though

Comment: Also, using extender looks like a generic version of my subscribe approach. I was hoping for an approach where I can parse value before it is passed to observable

Comment: Also, What my requirement is user should not be able to enter any character except numbers. It can be achieved in your example if I change `value` to `textInput` binding.

Comment: The `result` computed observable is the one you eventually write to. There's no extra subscription to `target`. By creating an in-between layer that only lets through valid data, you make sure you do not trigger any subscriptions on your "real" observable. So, in its own way, this meets your requirement of "parsing the value before it is passed to the observable".

Comment: I guess, I misunderstood it. I'll check it again. Thanks

Comment: Sadly, <input type="number"> is horribly broken in IE (at least up to 11). Depending on user culture, the browser might silently send a different value than the user actually typed.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Knockout Validation](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/knockout-validation) | [LIVE PEN](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/ORRqXJ):

```
<input data-bind="value: Number">

ko.validation.init();

function VM() {
    var self = this;
    self.Number = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true,
        pattern: {
            message: 'Invalid number.',
            params: /\d$/
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(window.v=new VM());
```

Comment: This will validate to numbers but will allow user to enter alphabets. I dont want that. Also, adding another lib is not something I'm looking for.

Comment: Right on, I wasn't sure if KO.Validate might have a way to avoid JQuery like you wanted while still getting the result. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Following is a **mimic** of `knockout`'s `textInput` binding, but with custom parsing. Note, I know, this has added few extra lines of duplicate code but I guess its worth.

I thought of creating my custom code, but reinventing the wheel will have lots of issues, hence appreciating Knockout teams effort and copying it.

[Numeric Only - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/w5dh36jv/5/).

[Characters Only - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/w5dh36jv/6/)

I have updated code in following

- **updateModel**: To fetch only parsed value from element. This will prevent updating incorrect value.
- **updateView**: To check if user have entered incorrect value. If yes, replace previous value, else update previous value as current value and proceed.

**Usability**

I have tried to increase scope of this binding beyond this question. I have added a special data attributes (`data-pattern` and `data-flag`) to create regex will parse accordingly.