# knockout textInput binding on number input field not updating on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, microsoft-edge

I seem to have hit an Edge browser specific issue with number input fields and knockout textInput binding.

I have the latest edge version, namely:
Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0; Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393

Until the anniversary update, the number input fields did not do anything with up/down arrows on Edge like they do on Chrome/Firefox. However, the latest version seems to have made some changes such that the value visible differs from what knockout has in the bound variable.

Here is the jsfiddle; try to change the value using up/down arrows:

https://jsfiddle.net/nkkfmLmc/13/

Html:

```
Amount:
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" data-bind="textInput: amount" />
<br />
Current Amount $<span data-bind="text:amount()"></span>
```

JS:

```
function PersonViewModel(amount) {
   this.amount = ko.observable(amount);
}

ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel(51.22));
```

The value updates correctly if the number is typed-in instead.

Any confirmation of the Edge issue or workaround(short of not using the number input type altogether) would be appreciated .

Comment: I had a different issue but might help: [Custom Input Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394445/number-input-box-in-knockout-js). Input type have special implementations and can have different behaviour in different browsers. If possible try to use `type="text"`

Comment: The reason why I want to use the number type is that the correct keyboard opens up on mobile browsers and even Chrome and Firefox add nifty features to number inputs (validations, spinner, keyboard arrow support).
Also, using a custom two-way binding is very disrupting for a user. Say the miminum allowed value is 1000, the 10000 was in the box. Now user removes the leading 1 to put in 5, but the custom binding would have changed the number to 1000, leading to sub-optimal experience.

Comment: @AVS did you find a fix? we have similar issue with Firefox, but it is the oppositite. It updates when we use up/down but not when entered manually.

Comment: @MBen No, I wasn't able to find any resolution for Edge. However, I use number fields with Firefox extensively and they work fine for me.