# HTML input with specified pattern

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a input text box of type 'text'. My requirement is this text box can accept only digits and decimal points [which is optional]. I can't use step because step will mandate decimal points after digits as I have few scenario where I don't want to use decimal point.
For example, If my drop down selection based on transaction count then text box should not allow decimal points to enter.
Second example, If my drop down selection is transaction amount then the text box should allow me to enter input with decimal point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number input box in Knockout JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394445/number-input-box-in-knockout-js)

Comment: Thank you @AldoRomo88 . Will try to implement in same way

Answer (score 0):

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32169/

sounds like maybe you are looking for the knockout extender
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

in the  fiddle  I basically copied the code from the knockout documentation http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32169/  by changing the precision value you decide how many decimal places to round to.

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function (target, precision) {
    //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.pureComputed({
        read: target,  //always return the original observables value
        write: function (newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
                newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue),
                valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;
};


function model() {
  var self = this;
  myvalue1 = ko.observable('').extend({ numeric: '0' });
  myvalue2 = ko.observable('').extend({ numeric: '2' });
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);

});
```