# Knockout observable incorrectly changing result of a math calculation when value is input

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Summary: an equation is changing its output when the observable value it uses is input by the user rather than set via another variable. The output of the equation is also modified by the order of the equation, but only when the user inputs the value.

I have an equation which looks as follows:

```
            var numMinions = Math.floor(
              customDifficultySettings.mandatoryMinions() +
                worker.star.distance() * customDifficultySettings.minionMod()
            );
```

worker.star.distance() is pulling a value from the star's array of information and should be ignored for the purposes of this question. It will return an integer.

Values for minions are fed into it through an array of difficulties:

```
var difficultyInfo = [
      {
        // Easy
        customDifficulty: false,
        minionMod: 0.2,
        mandatoryMinions: 1
      },
      // more difficulty levels
      {
        // Custom
        customDifficulty: true,
      }
```

Later on the observable is updated to match the selection:

```
      if (
        !difficultyInfo[model.newGameDifficultyIndex() || 0].customDifficulty
      ) {
        customDifficultySettings.mandatoryMinions(
          difficultyInfo[model.newGameDifficultyIndex() || 0].mandatoryMinions
        );
        customDifficultySettings.minionMod(
          difficultyInfo[model.newGameDifficultyIndex() || 0].minionMod
        );
      }
      // Used to hide custom input fields if not the custom difficulty level
      if (
        difficultyInfo[model.newGameDifficultyIndex() || 0].customDifficulty
      ) {
        customDifficultySettings.customDifficulty(true);
      } else {
        customDifficultySettings.customDifficulty(false);
      }
```

The view model for this is as follows:

```
var customDifficultySettings = {
  mandatoryMinions: ko.observable(),
  minionMod: ko.observable(),
```

If a "custom" difficulty is selected, then fields are exposed to allow the user to update the values via fields:

```
document
  .getElementById("game-difficulty")
  .insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterend",
    '<div class="sub_options" id="custom-difficulty-settings" data-bind="visible: customDifficultySettings.customDifficulty()">' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<div><input type="number" style="width: 50px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-bind="textInput: customDifficultySettings.mandatoryMinions" />' +
      '<span style="margin-left: 6px;"></span><loc>Mandatory Minions</loc></label>' +
      '<span class="info_tip" data-bind="tooltip: \'!LOC:Number of additional Commanders in every system.\'">?</span></div>' +
      '<div><input type="number" style="width: 50px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-bind="textInput: customDifficultySettings.minionMod" />' +
      '<span style="margin-left: 6px;"></span><loc>Minion Modifer</loc></label>' +
      '<span class="info_tip" data-bind="tooltip: \'!LOC:Mandatory Minions + Star Distance * Minion Modifier = number of additional enemy Commanders.\'">?</span></div>' +
      "</div></div>"
  );
```

So, for example, when `customDifficultySettings.mandatoryMinions = 1` and `customDifficultySettings.minionMod = 0` I'd expect `numMinions = 1`. This works as expected for every difficulty where the values are pulled from the `diffInfo` array.

However, if I select the custom difficulty and enter the number 1 into the Mandatory Minions field, and a Minion Modifier of 0, then I get `numMinions = 10`. It gets weirder in that if I change the equation to:

```
            var numMinions = Math.floor(
              worker.star.distance() * customDifficultySettings.minionMod() +
                customDifficultySettings.mandatoryMinions()
            );
```

then input the same values, I get `numMinions = 01`.

I'm assuming I'm taking the input in incorrectly and that it's not being returned as a number when coming in via the string, but I'm unsure how I should modify the input to correct this.

I'm at a loss on this one. It's my first experience working with Knockout.js.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the "quick patch" would be to just cast the variable to a number, because it seems like the observable actually has a string inside it, instead of a number. This then means that strings like `'1'+'0'='10'` are the result of plain string concat.
So you can first parse the number as Number():

```
var numMinions = Math.floor(
          Number(customDifficultySettings.mandatoryMinions() || 0) +
            worker.star.distance() * customDifficultySettings.minionMod()
        );
```

I am calling this a quick patch because i am not really aware of how "late" this snipet executes in your flow. You best way to solve this correctly is to parse the number as high up as you can, to make sure other parts before this are not affected as  well

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I ended up figuring it out a little earlier today and have posted the answer I went with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseFloat` in Your computation.

```js
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    
    this.firstValue = ko.observable(0);
    this.lastValue = ko.observable(0);
    
    this.fullValue = ko.computed(function() {
      var firstValue = self.firstValue();
      var lastValue = self.lastValue();
      return parseFloat(firstValue) + parseFloat(lastValue);
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <p>
    <label for="value-first">First Value</label>
    <input id="value-first" type="text" data-bind="textInput: firstValue" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="value-last">Last Value</label>
    <input id="value-last" type="text" data-bind="textInput: lastValue" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="value-full">Full Value</label>
    <input id="value-full" type="text" data-bind="textInput: fullValue" />
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Moreover, I would suggest You also to initialize the observables with a default value.

You can also use a custom numeric-only solution for Your textboxes: [Number input box in Knockout JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39394445/4845566)

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I ended up figuring it out a little earlier today and have posted the answer I went with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extender to make sure your observables are always numeric. IMO, that's a bit nicer than subscribing.

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.pureComputed({
        read: target,  //always return the original observables value
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
                newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : +newValue,
                valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;
};
```

(This is actually taken from the [docs](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)!)

And then you would define your VM like this:

```
var customDifficultySettings = {
  mandatoryMinions: ko.observable().extend({ numeric: 0 }),
  minionMod: ko.observable().extend({ numeric: 0 }),
```

Change `0` to however many digits you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out that the observables were returning strings, which was causing addition to simply concatenate them. I added the following under the declaration of the view model:

```
customDifficultySettings.mandatoryMinions.subscribe(function(value) {
  customDifficultySettings.mandatoryMinions(
    Math.max(0, Number(Number(value).toFixed(0)))
  );
});
customDifficultySettings.minionMod.subscribe(function(value) {
  customDifficultySettings.minionMod(
    Math.max(0, Number(Number(value).toFixed(2)))
  );
});
```